# New motherboard can't detect any RAM sticks?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure, computer-building

I am trying to build a computer with the following parts:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X with Cooler Master RR-212S-20PK-R1 heatsink

GPU: GIGABYTE Geforce RTX 2060

Mobo: Asus ROG Strix B450-F

RAM: GeIL EVO SPEAR 16GB (2 x 8GB)

HD: Hitachi Ultrastar A7K3000

PSU: Cooler Master Extreme Power RS-600-PCAR-E3

Case: Phanteks Eclipse P300

For some reason, the computer will not boot up to POST. I purchased a motherboard beep speaker, and every time I boot up I get the same pattern: one long, two short. According to ASUS's help, this means there is a memory issue, presumably with the RAM. I have tried shuffling the sticks around, using one stick, both sticks, no sticks, and completely different sticks of RAM from another computer - every time, I get the same beep error and no POST. What could be causing a new motherboard to not detect any sticks of RAM? Is this even a problem with the RAM?

E: I would also like to note that the motherboard's on-board error light - which I only just understood it had - is also glowing yellow, which means a problem with the DRAM.

Comment: It sounds like the ram specs dont match what the motherboard requires. RAM can be surprisingly difficult to spec correctly, and you have not detailed the specs for the RAM modules you are using.

Comment: I went out and bought new sticks of ram, Corsair Vengeance LPX, which were explicitly listed as being compatible with the motherboard I'm using Still no luck. Still a yellow light. Is there any explanation for why a new motherboard wouldn't be detecting ANY ram whatsoever?t

Comment: Faulty motherboard.